# How do I append something to a node when it's in detail page

Tags: 7

I'm writing a module that appends content to a node. I'm doing this using `hook_process_node` :

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['body'][0]['#markup'] .= '<p>My content</p>'; 
}
```

How can I put a condition here to tell Drupal to only append content when the node is being displayed on a detail page, i.e. not in an index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "detail page" you mean the full node page, you can check the current view mode:

```
if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full') {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `$variables['view_mode']`. You probably need to define a "Full content" view mode on your display settings of the node bundle. It will probably say "default" when "Full content" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

What is your detail page url?

if its **"domain/content/details"**, then use below condition inside your hook_prepocess_node.

First find your content type. for example, i'm assuming $variables['type'] = your_content_type.

```
if($variables['type'] == 'your_content_type' && arg(0) == 'content' && arg(1) != '') {
  // write your condition here.
}
```